# "votes answers views" alignment is off

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

It's one of those once-you've-seen-it-you-can't-stop-seeing-it bugs.

On the "Top Questions" feed from the main page, on all sites, when there are no answers to a question:

[image]

In primary-unified.css, it would need something like:

```
.narrow .status {
    padding: 7px 6px;
}

.narrow .votes {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}

.narrow .views {
    border: solid 1px transparent;
}
```

to make them all line up.

Comment: It looks like the alignment is correct for questions with at least one answer, where there's the green border or green background. That thing seems to affect the alignment.

Comment: I was going to make a joke about pluralization bugs, then I noticed [the header on the meta meme page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/313143). "*While at the time it was seen as light-hearted fun, that context (and Jeff) are long gone; the use of this is just confusing and definitely not in line with our Code of Conduct.*". Oh wow, Jeff has finally become an unperson. We have always been ---at war with Eurasia--- living by the Code of Conduct. Please be a productive citizen and flag any untruths that might suggest otherwise. Nice!

Comment: Your recommended fix would break the layout for questions that have more than 0 answers, since the answer box for those questions have a 1 pixel border. I believe that the 7px vertical border in the other boxes was used to account for the 1 pixel border around the answers box when there 0 or more answers. I think a better solution would be to apply the same padding to all the boxes (6px) and apply a 1 pixel transparent border to all of them by default. Which is overridden for the answers box when there are more than 0 answers.

Comment: Also, this issue was also recently posted as an answer on Meta.SE here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316355/299995

Comment: It always amazes me that people actually _notice_ those pixel imperfections...

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thanks; I tried it using the Firefox developer tools and added what I found was needed to the question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I went to send that revision to the Ministry of Love, but was daunted by the fact that no less a luminary than Tim Post had approved it. :(

Comment: One of many possible quick fixes could be a 1px transparent border by default :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak the next time I'm prevented form using a meme by the code of conduct I'm going to come to your house and ...*muffled screams*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, and some other stats-related alignment issues, have been fixed. Thanks for reporting! Sorry it took so long :)

Comment: Alignment still looks off to me.  Are we all getting the same stylesheet?

Comment: @billynoah It’ll be built out in the morning - just landed late in the day :)